# Generating lists of nested objects in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, nested-lists

Hi I keep running into a problem on trying to figure how I can create lists in Rails. My problem is I have a Team object, then I have a fixture object which contains a hometeam and awayteam, I want to be able generate the fixtures automatically, e.g. I have 20 teams so each team has 38 games they need to play each team home and away, how can I create a fixtures list to meet these requirements or is it possible in Rails. By making each team play everyone at home once it will create all the away fixtures also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby Array has a method `combination` that does the job. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-combination

Something like

```
teams = Team.all.to_a # or any selection of teams
teams.combination(2) do |first_team, second_team|
  Fixture.create!(hometeam: first_team, awayteam: second_team)
  Fixture.create!(hometeam: second_team, awayteam: first_team)
end
```

Will create all 380 fixtures for 20 teams.

Comment: Hi I tried putting that method inside my index method in my Fixtures Controller(maybe this is completely wrong I am a beginner to Rails) but I am getting this error ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in FixturesController#index

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: home_team, away_team
Rails.root: C:/Users/GCD/Desktop/result_predictor

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/fixtures_controller.rb:11:in `block in index'
app/controllers/fixtures_controller.rb:10:in `combination'
app/controllers/fixtures_controller.rb:10:in `index'